# Use WCF to let two application to communicate?

Tags: c#, wcf

First, let's say I don't want to use duplex channel and this is not a Client to Server senerio.  I should called... Client to Client?

I have two Form Application: App1 on my computer and App2 on another computer
Each of them should be hosting a WCF Service, App1 has App2's WCF Reference and App2 has App1's WCF Reference.

I wonder if I can do like that above, so I can have senerio:

1. In App1, click button open connection to App2's WCF, send message to
   App2
2. App2's WCF recevie message, display on the form.
3. App1 close connection. (App1 application is not closed)
4. App2, click button open connection to App1's WCF, send message to
   App1
5. App1's WCF recevie message, display on the form.
6. App2 close connection. (App2 application is not closed)

So in above senerio, you can see both application is running, they can freely to establish their own connection to another application's WCF.

I wonder if that's even possible?  Because I am thinking when I establish a connection to WCF, it should create a new process on the established WCF side.

And is it even possible to have a FormApplication running like that to use WCF receving message?

Comment: I would recommend to use namedpipes for that purpose, it seems more appropriate for your case

Comment: @Hohhi yes, that would be the case, but what I am asking is just to see if that's possible to do it with above setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This scenario is possible - though there could be some "quirks":

- Administrator rights could be needed to host a WCF service
- What happens if one of the apps is not started (you need to implement proper handling of such situation)
- IF the computers are not in the same LAN it could be impossible to connect without opening the firewall/port forwarding

You don't provide enough information to suggest alternatives...

Comment: Oh sorry, I am not asking for alternative, I just want to know if that's even possible to do it with WCF.  I know I can self host wcf with console application, but I am still wonder how to host it with a WinFormApp and use it to receive message from other application.

Comment: ok - self-hosting is practically the same in console and winforms... just use the `ServiceHost` class... please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of help...

Comment: It does not change it whether it is a WinForm or a Console, it is possible. WCF allows you to implement practically any communication scenario you can think of. But this does not mean it is good for everything, so do consider alternatives, please.

Comment: @Yahia I see, actually that's what I want to know.  Because when I create a WCF Application, it is just a library, I have no idea where is then entry point that host the service...

Comment: @Hohhi The reason doing this senerio is purely for testing if is possible to commnicate with other Web Service (and my self learning :D).  We were trying to use the WCF to communicate with another Web Service not WCF. but I am just taking WCF as example.  And they will not be on same LAN, their departments is going to sort out the stuff.